# $L^{p}$ spaces for complex measures

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, complex-integration, total-variation

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{A})$ be a measurable space and $\mu\colon\mathscr{A}\to\mathbb{C}$ a complex measure (i.e. a $\sigma$-additive function from $\mathscr{A}$ to $\mathbb{C}$). Then $\mu$ can be decomposed into a (unique) real and imaginary part. In other words, there are (finite) signed measures $\mu_{1},\mu_{i}\colon\mathscr{A}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mu=\mu_{1}+i\mu_{i}$. The [Jordan decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_decomposition_theorem) lets us split the real and imaginary part of $\mu$ into finite positive measures $\mu_{1}^{+},\mu_{1}^{-},\mu_{i}^{+},\mu_{i}^{-}\colon\mathscr{A}\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ such that $\mu_{1}=\mu_{1}^{+}-\mu_{1}^{-}$ and $\mu_{i}=\mu_{i}^{+}-\mu_{i}^{-}$. So we have
$$\mu=(\mu_{1}^{+}-\mu_{1}^{-})+i(\mu_{i}^{+}-\mu_{i}^{-}).$$
Then a measurable complex valued function $f\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ is called integrable with respect to the complex measure $\mu$ if and only if the real and imaginary part of $f$ are both integrable with respect to the measures $\mu_{1}^{+}$, $\mu_{1}^{-}$, $\mu_{i}^{+}$ and $\mu_{i}^{-}$. If $f=f_{1}+if_{i}$ (with $f_{1}$ and $f_{i}$ real-valued) is integrable with respect to $\mu$, then its integral is defined to be
\begin{align*}\int_{\Omega}f \ \text{d}\mu&:=\int_{\Omega}f_{1} \ \text{d}\mu_{1}^{+}-\int_{\Omega}f_{1} \ \text{d}\mu_{1}^{-}+i\int_{\Omega}f_{1} \ \text{d}\mu_{i}^{+}-i\int_{\Omega}f_{1} \ \text{d}\mu_{i}^{-}\\
&=\int_{\Omega}f_{i} \ \text{d}\mu_{1}^{+}-\int_{\Omega}f_{i} \ \text{d}\mu_{1}^{-}+i\int_{\Omega}f_{i} \ \text{d}\mu_{i}^{+}-i\int_{\Omega}f_{i} \ \text{d}\mu_{i}^{-}.
\end{align*}
I was studying complex measures, but the concept of $L^{p}$ spaces is very unclear to me in this case. I can't find any proper literature about it either. Can someone explain to me what is going on here?

I have a few questions in particular:

1. Can we make sense of the space $L^{p}(\Omega,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ for $1\leq p\leq\infty$?
2. Can we define a $p$-norm on this space? Is this norm also complete?
3. In the case $p=2$, do we still have a (complete) inner-product space?

I think the [total variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation) $|\mu|$ (which is a finite positive measure) of a complex measure $\mu$ has something to do with it, but I can't figure it out the details myself.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could just define $L^p(\mu) := L^p(|\mu|)$.

Comment: Your integral $\int f d\mu$ seems wrong. In general, the function of two argumetns $\langle f, \mu \rangle = \int f d\mu$ is a _bilinear_ form on the space $\mathscr{U}^\infty \times \mathsf{M}_\mathbf{C}^b$  of bounded universally measurable functions times the space of bounded complex measures. In other words, with $f = f_1 + if_2$ and $\mu = \mu_1^+ - \mu_1^- + i (\mu_2^+ - \mu_2^-)$ you should get 8 terms in the expansion of $\langle f, \mu \rangle.$